# Pointers in C. Local variable in the void function and scope

Tags: c, pointers, variables, local, void

Is it possible to create and insert a new element in a list of pointers in the scope of another function? This code only work if I call `printf` within `insertEntry` function where I've created local variable `n2_4` otherwise the output is

> -1247318248 Segmentation fault

I thought if I use pointers I could create and insert a new element in a list of pointers everywhere I want it. But it's something like local variable limited visibility scope. Or I'm mistaken?

Or I need to use function that can return one pointer insted of  `void insertEntry` fuction for such  purposes?

```
    // Function to insert a new entry into a linked list. 
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int            value;
    struct entry   *next;
};

void insertEntry(struct entry *insertion, struct entry *previous)
{
    struct entry  n2_4;
    n2_4.value = 299;
    struct entry *N2_4 = &n2_4;

    insertion->next = previous->next; // set n2_3.next to point to whatever n2.next was pointing to
    previous->next = insertion;       // set n2.next to point to n2_3

    insertion->value = 250;

    N2_4->next = insertion->next;
    insertion->next = N2_4;
}

void printPlist(struct entry *list_pointer)
{
    while (list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0) {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{


    struct entry   n1, n2, n3, n2_3;
    struct entry   *list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0;    // Mark list end with null pointer

    printPlist(list_pointer);

    insertEntry(&n2_3, &n2);

    printPlist(list_pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't use function (non-static) local variables outside the function. They go out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is dynamic memory allocation, take a look at [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

Basically local variables "disappear" when you return from the function. Memory dynamically allocated lives on until you explicitly call `free`.

Hope this helped, good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! I've just read about pointers and haven't yet  reached to dynamic memory allocation.